# Why is "speak" a class 4 strong verb?

Tags: verbs, germanic-languages

I've been trying to understand the how strong verbs in Germanic languages work, and reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb) I understand that class 4 strong verbs originated from, in PIE, vowel + a sonorant (*m*, *n*, *r*, or *l*).

But there seems to be many words whose vowel is not followed by *m*, *n*, *r*, or *l* but are of class 4. For example, German *sprechen* and Dutch *spreken* and English *speak* is class 4, yet in Old English and Old Dutch the same word seems to be a class 5.

In the article it is noted that

> *Get, speak, tread* and *weave* were originally of class 5, whereas *swear* was originally class 6.

How did these verbs "switch" class? And how can a verb like *speak* become a class 4 verb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a general levelling pattern in the verb morphology of Germanic languages. Wiktionary otherwise mentions "speak" as a strong **class 5** verb, primarily due to the fact that it used to be "spake" in the past tense. The reason it became classified as a **class 4** verb is that it replaced the older form, "spake", with a (possibly analogous) form "spoke" that matches the class 5 pattern of `e/a > o` (break/broke, tear/tore, wake/woke etc.); additionally, some other class 4 verbs, like "get" were borrowed.

There was no switching of verb classes when it came to the verbs you mentioned: the Great Vowel Shift basically tore apart class 5 and spread its verbs around after they analogised, likewise with class 6. It's more of a change of terminology than an actual switch of ablaut class. The example you gave, "swear", hasn't really changed that much: in Old English it was `swere/swōr` and in modern English it's `swear/swore`. The disintegration of classes 5 and 6 also took place with class 7 and class 2. There's still class 1, class 3 and class 4 strong verbs that remain partially regular and semiproductive in a variety of dialects.

As for other languages' verb classes, it's again due to their vowels' history and entirely unrelated to that of English.